# Vue.js - Render issue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to create a component, that can show/hide on click, similar to an accordion.

I have the following error and I don't know why:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "is_open" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive
>   data properties in the data option.  (found in root instance)

```
<div id="app">
    <div is="m-panel" v-show="is_open"></div>
    <div is="m-panel" v-show="is_open"></div>
</div>

</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="comp_a.js" ></script>
<!--<script src="app.js" ></script>-->
</html>

Vue.component('m-panel', {
  data: function() {
      return {
          is_open: true
      }
  },
    template: '<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>'
})

new Vue({
    el:'#app',
})
```

Comment: Is it just an example, or have you indeed written `<script>` outside `<body>` element, and the script itself outside `<html>` element? Do you have any errors in console apart that message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems a little confused, your `is_open` is in your component but you  are trying to access it in the parent. You just need to make sure this logic is contained inside your component. The easiest way is to simply place an event on the relevant element in your component template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Toggle when button is clicked-->
    <button @click="is_open=!is_open">
      Open Me!
    </button>
    <span v-show="is_open">
      I'm Open!
    </span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ytw22k3w/

Answer (score 0):

Because u used is_open property in '#app instance' but u didnt declare in it,u decladed in 'm-panel component' which has no relation with it.Try something like this can avoid it.

```
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
       is_open:''
    }
})
```